# python -vを実行した時のエラーっぽい標準出力について

Tags: python

Macでpython -vと実行すると後述の標準出力が出ます。これを
出ないようにしたいのですがどうしたらよいでしょうか？

この標準出力を見ても特にエラーのようなことは書かれてないので
どうしたらよいか迷っています。

ちなみに、バージョンは出力されないです。また、pythonだけの入力ですとこういうったことは出ないです。
pythonをいったんアンインストールして、anacondaでインストールし直す作業をしました。
アンインストールした時点でこういう状態になっていて、何か余計なことをやったような気もしています。

以下標準出力。

```
    yokoyama@MBPY:~$ python -v
    import _frozen_importlib # frozen
    import _imp # builtin
    import sys # builtin
    import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
    import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
    import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
    import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    # installing zipimport hook
    import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    # installed zipimport hook
    # /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc matches /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/__init__.py
    # code object from '/Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc'
    # /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-36.pyc matches /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py
    # code object from '/Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-36.pyc'
    import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1073f8780>
    # /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-36.pyc matches /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/aliases.py
    # code object from '/Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-36.pyc'
    import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1074322b0>
    import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1073f82e8>
    # /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-36.pyc matches /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/utf_8.py
    # code object from '/Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-36.pyc'
    import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10743c0b8>
    import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
```

中略

```
    # extension module 'readline' loaded from '/Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-36m-darwin.so'
    # extension module 'readline' executed from '/Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-36m-darwin.so'
    import 'readline' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x107641cc0>
    import 'atexit' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
    # /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/rlcompleter.cpython-36.pyc matches /Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/rlcompleter.py
    # code object from '/Users/yokoyama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/rlcompleter.cpython-36.pyc'
    import 'rlcompleter' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x107641dd8>
    >>>
```

ちなみに、python -vでなくpython --versionとすると下記です

```
yokoyama@MBPY:~$ python --version
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--version` の省略は `-V`（大文字の `v`） なので、

```
python -V
```

とします。小文字の `-v` の役割は `verbose (trace import statements)` なのでそれで正常ですよ。